# The field is required (diagnostics)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a C# Web API, which has a method on a controller that takes a custom object. When calling this endpoint from my react application, I'm getting a 400 response from the API, with the error message below.

> The categoryConfiguration field is required.

I understand that the API is failing to deserialize the request payload, but I have no idea why.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateConfiguration(CategoryConfiguration categoryConfiguration)
{
    return Ok(); // Never hits this breakpoint
}
```

I suspect it may have something to do with the custom object inheriting from an abstract class, although I have read similar posts indicating that it should work.

```
public class CategoryConfiguration : SystemConfiguration
{
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category? Category { get; set; }
}
```

```
public abstract class SystemConfiguration
{
    // Loads of properties.
}
```

The correct handling would be for the method to be executed, but currently, it doesn't actually reach the breakpoint in the controller.

This API has many other controllers which all work, in the same way, the only difference is the use of the abstract class. I can see that the object is being sent up through the browser.

[image: Request payload]

I have tried using the from `[FromBody]` attribute which had no effect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the parameter format you are passing should be correct. Is the URL of the API you are calling correct? How do you call API and pass parameters? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue was down to some backend validation rules (Fluent validation), basically, the `timeout` field was required to be greater than one of the nullable fields which caused the error code of

> 'Timeout must be greater than or equal to ''.

This resulted in a failed validation and rejected the request. I was able to find these error messages using Postman.

[image]